# Can we import many documents from DocuSign through the API?

Tags: docusignapi

A customer of ours likes using DocuSign's bulk send feature to get a lot of employees to sign documents.

They want the ability to then import these signed documents into our software. We're thinking of creating a GUI in our software that lets them browse the folders in DocuSign, select which envelopes to import and then import them.

A user may want to import 50 envelopes at a time. In this case it would make a few API calls when the user is browsing through their folder, then it will make 50 calls to RequestDocumentPDFsEx to download the documents associated with each envelope. The API calls would probably be done serially unless they're really slow. In that case we may have to use 2 threads or more so that it completes in a decent amount of time.

We only have one customer at this time that is looking at using this feature and it would not be used very often, maybe once a month.

Will we run into a problem with rate limiting or breach any terms if we implement the above described solution?

We already have a certified integrator key for our integration that allows users to upload a handful documents at a time to be signed.

Comment: Hmm that's a good question, I don't believe there's a mass "import" or download API currently available.  I know through the REST API you can search for and retrieve sets of envelopes not just by folder but based on events, date ranges, etc using a single API call, but not aware of being to download a set of envelopes through a single API call.  I'll put some thought into this and see if I can come up with an option or two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're only options here are:

1. [DocuSign Retrieve](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/retrieve-quick-start-guide.pdf) - a separate, paid module that DocuSign offers used for bulk downloading
2. One API call per envelope download

*DocuSign Retrieve* - "Download envelopes, documents and data from DocuSign for use with external systems. DocuSign Retrieve runs on your system as a one-time request or on a recurring basis. Configure DocuSign Retrieve to specify file type and storage location."

Otherwise as you have suggested you'll need to make one API call per envelope download, either through the SOAP API or through the REST API.

Comment: Connect seems like a very viable option here if permitted (the Partner storing the client's document).

Comment: DocuSign Connect might work but I think it depends on the business needs.  As you know Connect is event based, so you need to wait for an event to trigger on a given envelope to have DocuSign push that data out.  If a given user just wants to download a bunch of envelopes any time of the day then Connect might not be the best solution, but it's a good mention...